# js newbie trying to understand the dom via ajax confusion (conceptual)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm a python/data guy mucking around in a little bit of web, fundamentally clueless about JS and the dom and all that.  So something really weird happened, and even though I found a solution, I'm trying to understand the mechanics of why.

**The scene: a common problem**

There's like a million prior SO questions that go along the lines of "I had some working jQuery/JS that manipulated some HTML.  Then instead of hard-coding the relevant HTML, I created it programatically somewhere else and dragged it in via AJAX.  Suddenly everything broke."

Invariably, the answer goes like this: "you can't do that.  Hook up your code to something higher up the parent-child chain, event delegation is a magic thing and it will save you."

So that happened to me, I spent an hour or so reading prior SOs and learning about event delegation, and, indeed, it saved me, and my code worked.

But I don't understand why it was broken in the first place.  So I'm hoping someone can explain the underlying theory to me, and that way I'll come to a deeper understanding of the whole dom bit.

**Some Broken Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#autopubs").load("pubslist.html");
// Obviously, the stuff in pubslist.html is what the next line was 
// supposed to work on
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
});
```

probably no surprises about the solution.  wrap autopubs in an outer div and hook the collapse thing to that. Done, worked, deeply dissatisfied.

But I still don't understand why this is necessary.  Here's my mental model of what the broken code should have been doing.

1. Ok, the document's finished loading!  Let's execute our code!
2. First line: let's go get this file and add it to the DOM. This is out there in the world as *state,* and now we're going to mutate it, as one does with state.
3. Ok, now it's part of the DOM.  We're done with that line.  Let's go to the next line.
4. Ok, now we want to hook up a bunch of event listeners to everything with the class collapse.  Cool, let's look up the present state of the DOM.  Hey look, there's all this stuff in there with the collapse class.  Bam.  Hooked up.

Except 4 never happened, because the second line of code apparently couldn't see all the stuff that the first line added.

Intuitively, there are two plausible reasons for this:

1. The second line executed before the first one finished getting the file in.  If that's true, then I've learned something important about javascript (or jquery, or ajax, or something): lines don't always execute in order, or at least don't always finish before the next one starts.
2. The first line didn't actually mutate any state at all.  The DOM isn't state.  It's something else, something... maybe even immutable?  The first line tinkered around with something else entirely, something the second line couldn't touch because it was trying to tinker with the DOM.

Honestly, both of those possibilities seem kind of bizarre to me.  But there's obviously something I fundamentally don't understand going on under the hood here.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first assumption is correct. When calling ajax its asynchronous which means it will run a callback when complete. In this case jquery already calls a callback to append the content to the div but that happens after a delay of maybe 100 to 200ms or so.

The other code however can be run instantly but doesn't find anything because the async call isnt finished yet.

In jQuery if you check the documentation for [load](http://api.jquery.com/load) you will see something along the lines of `(arg1, [arg2], [complete])` where complete will be a closure or callback function.

If you wrap the code within that callback function instead of below it than that code will be executed after the content is loaded and added.

**EDIT**

The load [load](http://api.jquery.com/load) is also one of the convenience / shorthand method in jquery. For more documentation check [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/ajax)

Furthermore the DOM is very mutable and your first line that does the request does perform an operation on the dom. Due to the fact that it is async it will tell the script to continue running while it waits for its data which is why it fails.

Hope this helps abit! You've got the right picture :)

Comment: So *that's* what asynchronous means in this context!  It all becomes clear now. :-)

Comment: If you need more info feel free to ask any time :)

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript makes heavy use of asynchronous behaviour. Lines execute in order within the same function, but that doesn't mean they "complete" their action.

If you look at the documentation for `load` (http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can see that it takes an optional `complete` parameter. That is a callback. It is a function that will be ran when the operation completes. Calling `load` itself only makes the loading start, sort of "in the background".

So you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#autopubs").load("pubslist.html", function() {
        $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        });
    });
});
```

The callback to load is ran after it completes.

Why your original hack-solution actually works? It attaches the event handler to an existing outer div, and the loaded HTML is put inside later, when it loads.

Comment: Delegating events is actually quite elegant and makes easier to work with code since delegation listens for new elements when they arrive in the dom which makes rebinding the same event to different elements redundant

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand the reason it's considered a hack is because the behavior being listened to is on a different element than the one being listened to, and in the case where you add the event listener to the wrapper it's not _semantically_ correct even though it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you should refer the new loaded DOM only on a 'complete' callback. Take a look here:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line did get executed, it changed the state. After that, you hooked an event to the change and that will get called everytime there is a change, but not for the first one since it has already happened before the event was hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.load` is asynchronous, meaning you need to provide any code to execute after the content is added via callback. You have a working example at the bottom of [the documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

As others stated JavaScript wont wait with finishing the load function before executing the following lines. Therefore, you can use the callback parameter of the load function (or any other function that takes time, like AJAX or animations). So your first assumption is correct. AJAX (asynchronous JS) is a huge thing, you should dig into it :)

Additionally, you still can use delegation in your case:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
    var collapse = $(this); // the individual $('.collapse') element triggering the event
});
```

This will bind the `show.bs.collapse` event to all `.collapse` elements, regardless if they exist now or are added later. Here the original selector is the **`$(document)`**. In simple words:

"Hey document, whenever the event `show.bs.collapse` gets fired on an element with the selector '.collapse', run the following code."

You distinguish between direct and indirect event delegation or binding. In your example, you use direct binding, since you are ultimately selecting all now-existing `.collapse` elements and then do stuff with them:

```
$('.collapse').on()
```

You have to understand that this works only for currently existing elements that get selected when running that line. This wont apply for dynamically added elements of the same class.